# Make an image appear from left to right using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I am very close to achieving my goal. I am trying to create an image to appear from left to right using jQuery. If you look at my [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/richchatfield/qbnwmyp1/) You will see that there is a wavy line that appears from left to right. There is also a 2nd wavy line that stretches from left to right.

I want to remove the wavy line that stretches from left to right but keep the wavy line that appears smoothly from left to right

Can some one help me?

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> - jsFiddle demo</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">

body {
background-color: #003366;
margin: 0;
}

#myImg
{
top: 0px;
width:0px;
height:200px;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
background-image:url('http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/richtestslide2.png'); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
opacity: 0.5;
z-index: 100;
}

#graphoverlaylines {
position:absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 300;
}

#waveline {
top: 0px;
width:0px;
height: 200px;
position:absolute;
left: 0px;
background-image:url('http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/waveline.png'); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
z-index: 250;

}

#baloon { width:381px; height:50px; position:absolute; left:0px; top:150px; z-index: 200;}
#baloon2 { width:381px; height:50px; position:absolute; left:0px; top:100px; z-index: 200;}
#baloon3 { width:381px; height:50px; position:absolute; left:0px; top:50px; z-index: 200;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
repeat();
});

function repeat()
{

$("#myImg").animate({
    top: '0px',
    width: '328px',
    height: '200px'
}, 6000,repeat);
$("#myImg").fadeOut(1000);
$("#myImg").animate({
    top: '0px',
    width:'0px',
    height: '200px',
}, 0);
$("#myImg").fadeIn(10);

}


});


$(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
repeat2();
});

function repeat2()
{
$("#waveline").animate({
    top: '0px',
    width: '380px',
    height: '200px'
}, 6000,repeat2);
$("#myImg").fadeOut(1000);

$("#waveline").animate({
    top: '0px',
    width:'0px',
    height: '200px',
}, 10);
$("#waveline").fadeIn(100);

}


});


</script>

</head>


<body>

<div>
<img id="waveline" src="http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/waveline.png">
</div>


<div>
<img id="myImg" src="http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/richtestslide2.png">
</div>
<div>
<img id="graphoverlaylines" src="http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/graphoverlaylines.png">
</div>



<div id="baloon3"><img src="http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/richtest3.png" width="381" height="50px" /></div>
<div id="baloon2"><img src="http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/richtest2.png" width="381" height="50px" /></div>
<div id="baloon"><img src="http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/richtest.png" width="381" height="50px" /></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This could be done with CSS alone.

Comment: Mind sharing how? A link to a tutorial? Snippet of code? Not an experienced coder here so any help you can give would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for jQuery to achieve this, CSS alone could do this.

You could use the parent `div` as a mask by applying `overflow: hidden` on it and animate its `width` from `0` to `381px`(image's width) using CSS [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

```css
body {
  background-color: #003366;
  margin: 0;
}
#myImg {
  top: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: url('http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/richtestslide2.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 100;
}
#graphoverlaylines {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 300;
}
#waveline-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: leftToRight 3s ease-in infinite;
  animation: leftToRight 3s ease-in infinite;
}
#waveline {
  top: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: url('http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/waveline.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 250;
}
#baloon {
  width: 381px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 150px;
  z-index: 200;
}
#baloon2 {
  width: 381px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 200;
}
#baloon3 {
  width: 381px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 200;
}
@-webkit-keyframes leftToRight {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 381px;
  }
}
@keyframes leftToRight {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 381px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="waveline-container">
  <img id="waveline" src="http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/waveline.png">
</div>
<div>
  <img id="myImg" src="http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/richtestslide2.png">
</div>
<div>
  <img id="graphoverlaylines" src="http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/graphoverlaylines.png">
</div>
<div id="baloon3">
  <img src="http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/richtest3.png" width="381" height="50px" />
</div>
<div id="baloon2">
  <img src="http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/richtest2.png" width="381" height="50px" />
</div>
<div id="baloon">
  <img src="http://www.tankten.com/codeimages/richtest.png" width="381" height="50px" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Chip! Perfect!

Comment: @RichChatfield - You're Welcome :)